# Range and Null Space are Complementary

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to do the following question, which is Exercise 2 on page 241 of *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze:

Let $T$ be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional space $V$, and let $R$ be the range [image] of $T$.

(a) Prove that $R$ has a complementary $T$-invariant subspace if and only if $R$ is independent of the null space $N$ of $T$ [$R \cap N = 0$].

(b) If $R$ and $N$ are independent, prove that $N$ is the unique $T$-invariant subspace complementary to $R$.

I am having trouble with even starting this problem. I do not have any intuition as why this would be true.

Comment: You can use that the sum of the dimension of the range and of the null space is equal to the dimension of $V$. You then have two subspaces which by assumption do not intersect and whose sum of dimensions equals the dimension of the space.

Comment: By rank-nullity, $\dim R + \dim N = \dim V$ and the question is asking about when we have a direct sum decomposition $V = R \oplus N$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\exists W$ subspace of $V$ such that $V=R\oplus W$ and $W$ is invariant under $T$. Note $V=R\oplus W$ simply means $V=R+W$ and $R\cap W=\{0\}$. By [theorem 6 section 2.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481745/861687),
$$\dim (V)=\dim (R+W)=\dim (R)+\dim (W)-\dim (R\cap W)= \dim (R)+\dim (W).$$
So $\dim (V)=\dim (R)+\dim (W)$. By rank-nullity theorem, $\dim (V)=\dim (R)+\dim (N)$. So $\dim (W)=\dim (N)$. It suffice to show $W$ is contained in $N$ or vice versa, to conclude $W=N$. Let $\alpha \in W$. Since $W$ is invariant under $T$, we have $T(\alpha)\in W\cap R=\{0\}$. So $T(\alpha)=0$. Thus $W\subseteq N$. Hence $W=N$.