# Annihlators of Intersects and Sums

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $V'$ be the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb{F}$. For each subspace $X$ of $V$, let
\begin{align*}
X^0:=\{f \in V' : f(x) = 0 \textrm{ for all } x\in X\}.
\end{align*}

Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$.

(a) dim $(U^0)$ = $n-$dim($U$).

(b) $U^0 \cap W^0$ = $(U+W)^0$.

(c) $(U\cap W)^0$  = $U^0 + W^0$.

Would appreciate some feedback on my proofs.

(a) Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, there exists some basis $\mathcal{U} := \{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m\}$ of $U$. Now, extend this basis to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for by adding the vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_\ell$ where $\ell + m = n$.
Now, let $\varphi_i$ be the function in $V'$ such that $\varphi_i u_k = 1$ if $i = k$ and $0$ otherwise. Also, let $\varphi_i v_k = 0$ for all $k$. Similarly, let $\psi_i v_k = 1$ if $i=k$, 0 otherwise, and let $\psi u_k = 0$ for all $k$. Then the set, $\mathcal{C} = \{ \varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n,\psi_1,\dots,\psi_\ell \}$ is a basis for $V'$. Now, if $\rho \in V'$ is a functional such that $\rho u = 0$ for some $u \in U$, $\rho$ must be a linear combination of $\{\psi_1,\dots, \psi_\ell\}$ else $\rho$ would not annihilate $u$. Thus there are $\ell$ many vectors in the basis of $U^0$. But $n = \ell + m$, so $\ell = n-m$ as desired.

(b) Let $\varphi \in U^0 \cap W^0$. Let $x \in U+W$. Then $x = u + w$ for some $u \in U, w \in W$. Now, $\varphi(x) = \varphi(u + w) = \varphi(u) = \varphi(w) = 0$, so $\varphi \in (U+W)^0$. Conversely, suppose $\psi \in (U+W)^0$. Let $x \in U+ W$, with $x = u +w$ for some $u \in U$ and $w \in W$. Now, $\psi (x) = 0$, but $\psi(x) = \psi(u+w) = \psi (u) + \psi(w)$, so $\psi(u)$ and $\psi(w)$ must both be 0, hence $\psi \in (U^0 \cap W^0)$.

(c) Let $\varphi \in (U \cap W)^0$. If $x \in u \cap w$ it can be written $\sum_{i = 0 }^m\alpha_i u_i$ for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}$, and $u_i$ basis vectors for the subspace. Similarly, it can be written as $\sum^n_{i = 0}\beta_i w_i$, with $\beta_i \in \mathbb{F}$ and $w_i$ basis vectors of $W$. Now, $\varphi(x) = 0$ which means $\varphi(\sum^m_{i = 0}\alpha_i u_i) = 0$ and $\varphi(\sum^n_{i = 0}\beta_i w_i) = 0$. This implies $\varphi \in U^0 + W^0$. Now let $\rho \in U^0 + W^0$, then $\rho = \varphi + \psi$ for some $\varphi \in U^0$ and $\psi \in W^0$. Using the same $x$ as before we get,
\begin{align*}
(\varphi + \psi)x = \varphi x + \psi x = \varphi (\sum^n_{i = 0}\beta_i w_i)  +\psi( \sum^m_{i = 0} \alpha_i u_i).
\end{align*}
These two terms are only 0 if $\varphi \in W^0$ and $\psi \in U^0$ which would imply $\rho \in (U\cap W)^0$.

In particular, I'm the least confident about the forward containment in part (c). I feel like I may have made some logical jumps without proper justification.

Comment: "the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so." Why have you posted (a) and (b), when you are least confident about the forward containment in part (c)?

Comment: Actually I think your "$\subseteq$" in (c) is incorrect. Why $\varphi(\sum^m_{i = 0}\alpha_i u_i) = 0$ and $\varphi(\sum^n_{i = 0}\beta_i w_i) = 0$ implies $\varphi \in U^0 + W^0$?

Comment: For (c) "$\subseteq$": Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $U\cap W$. Extend it and let $\{e_i\}\cup \{u_i\}$ and $\{e_i\}\cup \{w_i\}$ be a basis of $U, W$ respectively. Assume $\{e_i\}\cup \{u_i\}\cup \{w_i\}\cup \{f_i\}$ is a basis of $V$. Consider $\varphi=\psi+\tau$, where $\psi(e_i)=\psi(u_i)=0$, $\psi(w_i)=\varphi(w_i)$, $\psi(f_i)=\varphi(f_i)$ and $\tau(e_i)=\tau(w_i)=\tau(f_i)=0$, $\tau(u_i)=\varphi(u_i)$. (The values of $\psi,\tau$ on  basis vectors are defined, and so $\psi,\tau$ are well-defined.) It is immediate that $\psi\in U^0$ and $\tau\in V^0$

Comment: @QuantumSuperfield well I wasn't quite sure if there was anything missing for those parts as well.

Comment: @Asigan I think that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your (a) and (b) "$U^0 \cap W^0 \subseteq (U+W)^0$" part are fine.

---

For (b) your proof of "$U^0 \cap W^0 \supseteq (U+W)^0$",
$\psi (u) + \psi(w)=0$ does not imply both of them are zero, and hence your proof does not work.

*A proof for $U^0 \cap W^0 \supseteq (U+W)^0$*:
Assume $\psi\in (U+W)^0$, i.e. $\psi(x)=0$ for all $x\in U+W$.
Given any $u\in U$, since
\begin{equation*}
u=u+0\overbrace{\in}^{0\in W} U+W
\end{equation*}
and (by hypothesis) $\psi(x)=0$ for all $x\in U+W$,
we have $\psi(u)=0$.
Therefore by the definition of $U^0$, we infer $\psi\in U^0$.
The same argument gives $\psi\in W^0$ $\implies$ $\psi\in U^0\cap W^0$.

---

For (c) "$(U\cap W)^0 \subseteq U^0 + W^0$": (I have written in the comment, but for the completeness I repeat it)

Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $U\cap W$. Extend it and let $\{e_i\}\cup \{u_i\}$ and $\{e_i\}\cup \{w_i\}$ be a basis of $U, W$ respectively. Assume $\{e_i\}\cup \{u_i\}\cup \{w_i\}\cup \{f_i\}$ is a basis of $V$. Consider $\varphi=\psi+\tau$, where $\psi(e_i)=\psi(u_i)=0$, $\psi(w_i)=\varphi(w_i)$, $\psi(f_i)=\varphi(f_i)$ and $\tau(e_i)=\tau(w_i)=\tau(f_i)=0$, $\tau(u_i)=\varphi(u_i)$. (The values of $\psi,\tau$ on  basis vectors are defined, and so $\psi,\tau$ are well-defined.) It is immediate that $\psi\in U^0$ and $\tau\in V^0$.

For "$(U\cap W)^0 \supseteq U^0 + W^0$" your proof is overcomplicated.

*A shorter proof*: Select $\omega\in U^0 + W^0$. Assume $\omega=\psi_U+\psi_W$, where $\psi_U\in U^0,\ \psi_W\in W^0$. Then for all $x\in U\cap W$, $\psi_U(x)=0$ since $x\in U\cap W\subseteq U$ and $\psi_U\in U^0$. The same argument gives $\psi_W(x)=0$. Therefore
\begin{equation*}
\omega(x)=\psi_U(x)+\psi_W(x)=0\implies \omega\in (U\cap W)^0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: You may [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4554583/861687) alternative proof of (c).