# Exercise 2, Section 6.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, direct-sum

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W_1,…,W_k$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $V=W_1+…+W_k$ and $\dim(V)=\dim(W_1)+…+\dim (W_k)$. Prove that $V=W_1\oplus …\oplus W_k$.

**Approach (1):** Suppose $V=W_1+…+W_k$ and $\dim(V)=\sum_{i=1}^k \dim (W_i)$. Then $\dim (V)=\dim (W_1+…+W_k)= \sum_{i=1}^k \dim (W_i)$. By [theorem 6 section 2.3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481745/861687), $\dim (W_1+…+W_k)=\dim (W_1)+\dim (\sum_{i\gt 1}W_i)-\dim (W_1\cap \sum_{i\gt 1}W_i)$. By mathematical induction, $$\dim (W_1+…+W_k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \dim (W_i)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dim(W_j\cap \sum_{i\gt j}W_i).$$ So $\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dim(W_j\cap \sum_{i\gt j}W_i)=0$. Since $\dim(W_j\cap \sum_{i\gt j}W_i) \geq 0$, we have $\dim (W_j\cap \sum_{i\gt j}W_i)=0$. So $W_j\cap \sum_{i\gt j}W_i=\{0_V\}$, for all $1\leq j\leq k-1$. By lemma 1 section 6.6, $W_1,…,W_k$ are independent. Thus $V=W_1\oplus … \oplus W_k$. **Is my proof correct?**

**Approach (2):** Let $B_i$ be basis of $W_i$, $\forall i\in J_k$. Let $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^k B_i$. We show $B$ is basis of $V$. Since $V=W_1+…+W_k$, we have $V=\text{span} (B)$. Since $\dim (V)=\dim(W_1)+…+\dim (W_k)=n$, we have $\dim(W_1)+…+\dim (W_k)=|B_1|+…+|B_k|$. **How to show $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset$, if $i\neq j$?** so that we can conclude $|B_1|+…+|B_k|=|B|=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is correct. In (2), the notation $\cup$ is troublesome. Let us view basis as indexed families rather than sets. Denote $B_i=(v_{i,1},\dots,v_{i,n_i})$ and $B=(v_{1,1},\dots,v_{1,n_1},\dots,v_{k,1},\dots,v_{k,n_k})$ (thus allowing *a priori* repetitions but we shall soon see there are none). Since $n_1+\dots+n_k=\dim V$ and $\operatorname{span}(B)=V,$ $B$ is a basis of $V.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You’re correct. I’m using the term basis loosely. It should be ordered basis. But that don’t effect our problem, I think. We need to show cardinality of $B=(B_1,…,B_k)$ is indeed $\dim (V)$. We know $|B_1|+…+|B_k|=n_1+…+n_k=\dim (V)$. What if $\exists \alpha \in B_i\cap B_j$ for some $i\lt j$? Then clearly $|B|\lt \dim (V)$. So $B$ is not basis of $V$.

Comment: $B$ is not a set but an indexed family (possibly with repetitions a priori). So "$|B|$" and "$B_i\cap B_j$" are not relevant here. $B$ is sequence of $\dim(V)$ vectors. When $n$ vectors span a space of dimension $n$, they are necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: To my understanding, if a finite sequence has two same element, then that sequence is linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes, so we proved this cannot happen for $B,$ but this would not have been sufficient. We proved much more.

Comment: Wait a second. I saw “no subset of $V$ which contains fewer than $n$ vectors can span$(V)$” result in the book. Thus $|B|=n$. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: I would not formulate it in terms of sets but rather of sequences: if a family $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ spans a space of dimension $n$ then that *family* is linearly independent, i.e. $\sum\lambda_iv_i=0\implies\forall i\;\lambda_i=0$ (and therefore $v_i\ne v_j$ if $i\ne j$ but this is much weaker).

Comment: If you use on the result you quote, you obtain that $|B|=n$ but that is not the end of the story. You will have to use anyway the stronger theorem stating that if $|B|=n$ and $B$ spans $V$ (of dimension $n$) then $B$ is a basis for $V.$ So, better use this stronger theorem directly.

Comment: Yess. I’m so used to using set (maybe because of the book) that sequence feels bit uncomfortable. But I know sequence is better object to work with in this context, because it has “order” and element can repeat.